# Calculating the Herfindahl index across a list of data frames in R

Tags: r

I have the following data stored in a list:

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,100,rep=TRUE)))
df2 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,100,rep=TRUE)))
list = list(df1, df2)
```

How can I do the following:

1) For each column, obtain the share of each element in the column sum (i.e., each element divided by the column total) and then square the share

2) Take the sum of each column from step 1

The output, then, would be a list of 2 vectors (one for each of df1 and df2) containing 10 scores each.

My code, shown below, does not appear to be working. Any advice would be welcome. Many thanks in advance!

```
 do.call(cbind,lapply(list, function(x) {
 x1 <- ((x/colSums(x))^2)[col(x)]
 sapply(x1, function(y) sum(y))}))
```

Comment: maybe it should be `x1 <- (x/colSums(x))^2; colSums(x1)` in your function?

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr` you can use `mutate_all` to apply a function to all columns.  Then you can use `funs` to generate a function to evaluate.  Last, you can sum all columns with `colSums`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate_all(funs((./sum(.))^2)) %>% colSums

#     X1         X2         X3         X4         X5         X6         X7         X8         X9        X10 
# 0.01346280 0.01247748 0.01348066 0.01246220 0.01310924 0.01279258 0.01316828 0.01322423 0.01340310 0.01294876
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why my approach above doesn't work?